# THREE.js particle texture shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

As a training exercise I'm trying to recreate the scene from mercury demo "luma" ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBuoyegCeXI ). I do have some problems with point sizes though. I'm trying to scale pointSize based on distance between vertex and camera position but it leads to weird random scale-ups such as the one below.

[image: now that's a twinkle]

it only happens at some specific positions. The twinkle effect it leads to is actually quite cool and I think I'll implement it later on in some controlled manner but this unfortunately won't do. Here's the code for shaders: 
[vertex]

```
uniform vec3 cameraPos;

void main() {
 float baseSize = 32.0;
 float distance = sqrt(dot(position, cameraPos));
 gl_PointSize = baseSize / (0.1 * distance);
 gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

distance function gives me nothing for some reason, while sqrt(dot()) works, more or less.

[fragment]

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord); 
}
```

material code for three.js

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    texture: { type: "t", value: texture }
  },
  transparent: true,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  depthTest: false,
  vertexShader: document.getElementById('particleVertex').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById('particleFragment').textContent,
})
```

How can make it behave?

Comment: `dot(v, v)` is squared vector length. So why you get dist as `sqrt(dot(a, b))` instead of `sqrt(dot(pos - camPos, pos - camPos));`?

Comment: that's it, I knew it was something stupid. Thanks, it's working perfectly now.